# Handlebars.js on Amazon Linux cannot locate a view template

Tags: express, handlebars.js, amazon-linux

I have an Express application that uses Handlebars.js as a templating engine. I'm trying to get it running on an EC2 Amazon Linux instance; the server is running and it can connect to the database, but when I try to open the website in my browser, I get the following error: `Failed to lookup view "homepage" in views directory "/views"`.

The application works perfectly fine when I run it locally and on Heroku (I'm trying to move it off Heroku), so I have no idea what the issue here is. I deleted the `/var/log/messages` file, having not realized it wouldn't be regenerated (this is my first time using EC2), so I unfortunately can't look there for hints, but I do know that if I run `<environment variables> node server.js` in the Amazon Linux terminal, no errors occur.

The application has a `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` so I can keep it live with systemctl. I assume the error is to do with the configuration of that file. It's also being reverse-proxied with nginx, but this issue was present before I set that up.

Relevant code snippets:

/etc/systemd/system/lightbox.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lightbox
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/ec2-user/lightbox/server.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=Lightbox
User=ec2-user
EnvironmentFile=/home/ec2-user/lightbox/lightbox.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const routes = require('./controllers');
const path = require('path');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;

// handlebars init
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const helpers = require('./utils/helpers');
const hbs = exphbs.create({helpers});

// handlebars init
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// session init
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);

// session init
const sess = {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    cookie: {},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new SequelizeStore({
        db: sequelize
    })
};

// general express init
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session(sess));

app.use(routes);

// startup
sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('http://localhost:' + PORT);
    });
});
```

(Not including the .env file, but it's there, the secret is present and definitely being read by the server.)

Route that renders the homepage:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Post.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'title', 'text', 'created_at'],
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
                attributes: ['username', 'id']
            },
            {
                model: Comment,
                attributes: ['id']
            }
        ]
    })
    .then(dbPostData => {
        const posts = dbPostData.map(post => post.get({plain: true}));

        res.render('homepage', { posts, loggedIn: req.session.loggedIn });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't  need systemd to run a nodejs app. Share us the staktrace and a hello world of your app. I think there is some var which is confusing to nodejs base path

Comment: @JRichardsz This is the stack trace.
`Error: Failed to lookup view "homepage" in views directory "/views"
- at Function.render (/home/ec2-user/lightbox/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17)
- at ServerResponse.render (/home/ec2-user/lightbox/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
- at /home/ec2-user/lightbox/controllers/home-routes.js:36:13
- at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)`

I'm not sure what you mean by "share a hello world". I could rewrite server.js to serve a static html file to see what happens.

Comment: Do you have a view called "homepage"? What's its path?

Comment: @76484 Yeah, I do. The path is `views/homepage.handlebars`. Like I said, the app works fine if I run it without systemd/systemctl. I suppose I should look into how to run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I never resolved this error, but I did get the app functioning by reworking it to use PM2 rather than systemd.